# https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css This CDN link don't have refresh icon

Tags: fonts, angular6, font-awesome

I am using this link in my angular 6 application:

https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css

It works fine for me expcept refresh icon. Refresh icon is not displaying not even any square boxes.

Please help??

I just want to display my refresh icon by using only this CDN link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because there isn't a refresh icon in FA 5.

The refresh icon was part of Font Awesome 4.

In Font Awesome 5 you can use the `sync` icon instead. It looks the same as the refesh icon did but has a new name.

https://fontawesome.com/icons/sync?style=solid

The HTML for the solid sync icon would be:

```
<i class="fas fa-sync"></i>
```

The unicode is:

```
f021
```

You might find it helpful to use their shim or a kit when upgrading because quite a few things changed between versions:

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4

Comment: Glad to help @NishaYadav